# Regular expression - match character(s) at the end without using $ sign

Tags: javascript, regex

[image]Kindly visit this link.

[RegEx Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf#accesstoken=HbFVcA/luSyE6YsEy1U8)

Here it wants me to match a few set of words and a few must not be matched.

The problem is that it is not allowing me to use **`$`** sign.

I am not able to figure out how to do it..

A detailed explanation or link to the same will be a great help.

Comment: For level `It never ends`  it does not allow `$` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Come on... This is like the Euler project - you can share or ask for solution, but it defeats the whole purpose. :/

Comment: @ndn Not getting you

Comment: It's a personal challenge. It undermines the whole idea if you make good solutions widely available (like on SO).

Comment: @ndn Gotcha...!

Comment: Seems like `\b(to|sna)?fu\b` should match. Can you use word boundary's ? And your link https://alf.nu/RegexGolf#accesstoken=HbFVcA/luSyE6YsEy1U8 is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out the solution with **word boundaries**

**`/u\b/`**

This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fu(?!.)` for those samples. You can even omit the `f` for a better score.

Comment: Just `u(?!.)` will do! And it uses look-aheads!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir indeed.

Comment: This also worked, thank you! Mine one got me better score than this one though ;)